# How to write out data field as Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I store sql like `select * from classes where owner_id = #{@current_user.id}` in my database. 
Can any one tell me how write out the above sql as ruby code so the `#{@current_user.id}` can be replaced dynamically as the id of the current signed in user?

Comment: Uh... exactly like what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Without any security/input validation in mind, you could do like this:

```
q_template = "select * from classes where owner_id = %s"
```

and to "populate" it, you could do like this:

```
sample_input = "40"
new_query = q_template % sample_input
# this will create     q_template = "select * from classes where owner_id = 40"
```

If you end up using this, make sure you check your input for malicious things before feeding it to the database.

Comment: It works!!! You are awesome! Is there anyway that I can even store the variables in database like 'select * from users where id = %@id'. The reason I ask so is because I am trying to build a dynamic form driven by database entirely. Therefore, I won't be able to know what and how many paramateres to assign in my code.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.